# why do we use logistic function to build logistic regression.

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression

Why do we use logistic function to build logistic regression. I know the output value for logistic function bounds between 0 & 1, and bcos of this we can express as probability. Is this the reason we go for logistic function ?

Or is it because, if we plot the probabilities for an observation of being class 1 vs the observation, will form a S curve plot. And hence we use logistic function to model the behavior ? For example consider the case of credit card balance & default. If we plot the cumulative distribution of the probability of default given balance, then the plot we get is of shape S curve.

Could someone please explain this.

Regards,

Rohit

Answer (score 6):

The flippant answer is that if we used another function for the regression, we wouldn't call it logistic regression. -- That's not entirely flippant, as logistic regression part of the broad class of "[generalized linear models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model)", which attaches a "link" function to the output of a linear regression model. This allows you to have non-linear fitting, but with computational tractability close to that of a linear model. For logistic regression this link function is the [logit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) function, but you can certainly use other functions in a generalized linear model.

As you mention, the choice of logit (logistic regression) is due primarily to it's behavior of compressing the output between 0 and 1, with a smooth output between them. It is not, however, the only link function which does this. There are a number of other functions with this property, most notably the [probit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit_model) link function.

So why do so many people choose [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression), rather than some other generalized linear model? Well, that's mainly due to the interpretation of the output. For a logistic model, intermediate output values can be interpreted as the log [odds ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds_ratio) of being in the "1" category. Other link functions [don't have such a clear probabilistic interpretation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20523/difference-between-logit-and-probit-models).

Comment: Can you explain please in more depth what is this "link" function?

Comment: @Gulzar The link function is simply an arbitrary function which is applied to the output of a linear model to give you a generalized linear model. That is, instead of, for example, `y = mx + b` you have `y = f( mx + b )`, where `f()` is the link function. -- For GLMs in general there's no particular requirement for the form of that function.